# Expectation on the number of draws from 1 to N until current draw is smaller than the previous draw

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose there are N integers from 1 to N. Randomly draw from them without replacement. Suppose in the first draw, we get a. In the second draw, we get b. If a>b, we will stop drawing. If a < b, then we keep drawing until the number we get from the current draw is smaller than the number we get from the previous draw or until there is no number left. Suppose X is the total number of draws. For example, N= 8 and our first 3 draws are [2,3,4]. If our forth draw is 6, we can draw for the fifth time. If our forth draw is 1, we will stop drawing. Then X = 3. The question is to calculate the expectation of X.

I know that if N = 1, E[X] = 1. If N = 2, E[X] = 1.5. If N = 3, E[X] = 5/3. But how to generalize it to N?

Comment: Hint:  what's the probability that the first $n$ draws are increasing?  Note:  you need to say what value you assign to the case where you draw all the numbers in increasing order.

Comment: Note:  I don't understand why you say $E[x]=\frac {10}3$ when $N=3$.  $\frac {10}3>3$ and I would have thought that $3$ was the largest value you could possibly get on a single trial.

Comment: @Lulu Sorry when N=3, E[X] = 5/3. I have updated my post.

Comment: Yes, that's what I get.  the hint in my first comment should explain how to do it generally.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the sample space as permutations of length $N$, each having probability $1/N!$. (For example, if the first four draws are $2,3,1$ and we stop there, this event is represented by the union of all permutations that start with $2,3,1$.)

Following lulu's hint: If $X$ is the number of draws, then for $k > 1$, $\{X > k\}$ is the event that the first $k$ draws are in increasing order. Show that the probability of this occurring is $\frac{1}{k!}$.
Then, using the tail sum formula,
$$E[X] = \sum_{k = 0}^{N-1} P(X>k) = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(N-1)!}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just want to add one more detail for computing P{X>k}. In order for X to be larger than k, it means the first k numbers have to be in the ascending order. So we first pick k integer out of N numbers. Once picked, their order is determined. The rest n-k integer can be in any order. so P{X>k} = (N!/(k!*(N-k)!)) * (N-k)! / N!